# Maximum modulus principle problem

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I have the function $f$ which is holomorphic on the open unit disc $|z|<1$ and satisfies $|f(z)|\leq cos(\frac{\pi |z|}{2})$. I am asked to find $f$.

I know that I am supposed to use maximum modulus here, and I have a good feeling that $f(z)=0$ since near the boundary $|z|=1$, $cos(\frac{\pi |z|}{2})$ gets closer and closer to $0$. But I don't quite know how to say all of this rigorously. Also since I am not given that $f$ is holomorphic or continuous **on** the boundary $|z|=1$, I am finding it difficult to say something about how $f$ behaves near this boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the maximum modulus principle on discs of increasing radius centered at 0, and use that as you noticed, the bound tends to $0$ there.

In other words,
by the maximum modulus principle, for $0<r<1$, we have 
$$
\sup_{|z|\leq r}|f(z)|\leq \sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\leq\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi r}{2} \right)\right|
$$
Now take $r\uparrow 1$ and use that $\cos\left(\frac{\pi r}{2}\right) \downarrow 0$. So $f\equiv 0$, as you intuited.

edit: Some details. 
Fix $\epsilon>0$, $z_0\in D(0,1)$.

Find a $\delta>0$ so that $1-\delta<r<1\implies \left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi r}{2} \right)\right|<\epsilon$. Then, by the same chain of inequalities,
$$
\sup_{|z|\leq 1-\frac{\delta}{2}}|f(z)|\leq \epsilon
$$
We can find a $\delta'$ small enough so that $z_0\in D(0,1-\delta'/2)$ and the continuity estimate still holds, and $|f(z_0)|<\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon>0$, $z_0$ were arbitrary, $f\equiv 0$ on $D$.

Comment: So taking the limit I get $\sup_{|z|<1}|f(z)|\leq0$ right? I'm afraid I still don't understand why this works. Just from this statement about the supremum alone, couldn't it still be any number greater than zero?

Comment: @AzamatBagatov I'll add a couple of details

Comment: Does the fact that $|f|$ is bounded on the disc imply that $f$ is constant? Or must the upper bound for $|f|$ be attained at some point in the disc (i.e. $|f(z)| \leq |f(a)|$, some $a\in D(0,1)$) to conclude that $f$ is constant? Because if my first question is true then I think I can make sense of this

Comment: To your first question, no, think of $f(z)=z$. To the second, yes this is a standard application of the maximum modulus principle. I don't see how it relates to my answer though.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: It wasn't related, I just thought I came up with a more concise answer but it appears not. Thank you for clarifying this though, it was the limit part I was initially confused about but this makes sense now.

Comment: @AzamatBagatov no problem, good luck!